# How to check if every element of a collection is true (truthy) in Lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Documentation shows an example of

```
_.every([true, 1, null, 'yes'], Boolean);
```

but this just evaluates to Boolean, so it would work for both 'true' and true. What I'm looking for is a proper way to check for that. So far, the only thing I came up with is

```
_.every([true, true, true], _.identity);
```

but I'm not convinced it's the right way (not to mention, it obfuscates a lot its intention)

Comment: Your two examples work the same, though - `_.identity` would be like doing a conversion to a boolean via the constructor. A `"true"` still passes it. So, I'm not sure what the intention is.

Comment: Ouch, you're right. I suppose I wanted to double check that only actual booleans are checked and not converted/evaluated (truthy) from something else. I was wondering if there is a succint way to do it.

Comment: `_.every([true, true, true], x => x === true);` for example

Comment: Yeah, that I figured. I was just thinking if maybe there's something even simpler. But sure, a predicate specified directly would work, thanks.

Comment: Well, if you use Lodash FP you could shorten to `_.every(_.eq(true), arr)` but it's not *that* much shorter. Still being able to use `_.eq(true)` or, for example `_.gt(5)` to filter arrays might be more useful in the long run.